# type casting template

Tags: c++, templates

I am try to make a template that type casts and I got error on compiling following program.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
template<typename T,typename U>
T mycast(U u)
{
 return (T)u;
}
int main()
{
 double d= 10.6577;
 int j= mycast<int>(d) ;
 return 0;
}
```

please tell me where is problem and how to overcome?
Thanks

Comment: And what is the error message that you get?

Comment: it says , expected at line 3 i.e template<typename T,typename U>

Comment: That goddamn mystery error that everyone seems to get.  I hate that damn thing.  It's like someone along the line is trying to keep us all completely ignorant so that it becomes almost impossible to help.

Comment: `-1` for asking about a compiler error message without stating which compiler and what's the exact error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remove the `#include <iostream.h>` (because it should be `#include <iostream>`, but it's not needed anyway), then it compiles fine (in VS 2010).

Comment: I m using old turbo C++ 3.0 compiler so that is ok

Comment: @Atul : Then switch to a better (and newer) compiler.

Comment: @Atul: it's pre-standard compiler. Please, update it immediately.

Comment: @ prasoon and ybungalobill. ooh yes it is working fine on VC++.net 2005

Answer (score 0):

```
it says , expected at line 3 i.e template<typename T,typename U>
```

Atul try to change

```
int j= mycast<int>(d) ;
```

to

```
int j= mycast<int,double>(d) ;
```

P.S. I think you need to update your compiler :).